# Execute docker run through powershell script (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, docker

I have been searching for a way to execute a Docker run in a Powershell script, i.e. something in the lines off:

*Start-Process ([docker.exe, “docker run -v … -t …”])*

The purposes of putting my Docker run in a Powershell script is so I can use the Windows 10 scheduler in order for it to run my container (having a Ubunutu 18.04 base images with a bunch of bash scripts) which will perform a set of infrastructure process tasks.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of getting this done?

Sincerely,
/swepab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem through executing a Python script in the following manner:

```py
    import time
    import random
    import subprocess
    from pathlib import Path

    subprocess.call(["powershell.exe", "docker run -v 'mount path from my computer':'mounth path container' "dockerfile_ubuntu1804_windows10"])
```

I scheduled this and it works like a charm, running the image and building the container to execute the bash script I have made connected to the container.